# Geodesics in the product of two metric spaces

Tags: geometry, geodesic

I have to show the following:

Let $(X_1,d_1),(X_2,d_2)$ be metric spaces and $X=X_1 \times X_2$ be the space equiped with the product metric $(d_1^2 + d_2^2)^{1/2}$. If $\sigma:I \to X$ is a geodesic, then there exist $c,s \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and geodesics $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ such that for all $t \in I$ $$\sigma(t)=(\sigma_1(ct),\sigma_2(st))$$ 
I am really stuck here. I have only been able to show that $c^2 +s^2=1$ which does not help me at all.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what definition of geodesic are you using? I have seen about 3 different ones.

Comment: My definition is that a geodesic is an isometric map from an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ to a metric space.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $\sigma$ is a geodesic from $p = \sigma(0)$ to $q = \sigma(1)$, then consider $\pi_i\sigma$ where $\pi_i : X \rightarrow X_i$ is the projection. If $\sigma_i$ is a geodesic $\pi_i(p)$ to $\pi_i(q)$, what can you say about the relationship between the $\pi_i\sigma$ and the $\sigma_i$?

Comment: I don't understand how can you suppose the existence of $\sigma_i$. And even with this supposition, I don't see what could be the relationship between a random geodesic and $\pi_i \sigma$. I am sorry, I am really bad with this kind of arguments.

Comment: If $\sigma$ exists, can you see how to construct a geodesic in $X_1$ from $\pi_1\sigma$? If so, then that is such a geodesic $\sigma_1$. Drawing a diagram as though this were in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ may help.